# Formal definition of interpreter

Tags: language-agnostic

My book says:
If there is a language called L, and a language called L' , an interpreter written in L' is a program which realizes the partial function I(L) : (prog(L) x D) -> P(L) (D);
With D = data, or input, Prog(L) program written in L, I(L) interpreter written in L' which interprets the language L', P(L) result of the interpretation.
I don't understand why the domain is Prog(L)xD, why isn't just Prog(L), if I have a simple instruction written in python such as:

```
s=input('enter a value: ')
```

This case I understand why the domain is Prog(L)xD, but what if I have just:

```
s='hello'
```

This case there isn't any input, could someone explain to me why the domain is Prog(L)xD ?

Comment: Seems to me the `Prog(L)xD` represents the general case. The "hello" example is a specific case
where `D` is empty. In a practical sense, there are not many interesting programs that where
`D` is empty.

Comment: So in the first case the input is given by the user of the program, and in the second case the input is an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

@NealB partially addressed this in the comments, but even though there actually isn't data, the domain is still trivially `Prog(L)xD`, it's just that there's no data.

In fact, the fact that there's no input is part of its domain. Think of it this way: there will always be a set of valid inputs. This doesn't change for things that take no data - its valid data is the empty set. You're just specifying that you won't take input. If you have function `f() = 100`, for example, and tried to call it like `f(23)`, then clearly you've done something invalid.